# Duda menu con switch anidados JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que me piden hacer un menu para guardar prendas en un arraylist o mostrar las prendas del arraylist prendas.Prendas es una clase padre que tiene 3 clases hijas (Camisa, Pantalon y Calcetin) con atributos heredados y propios de cada clase.

Lo que pasa es que en cuanto inicio la aplicacion y guardo una prenda automaticamente me la muestra, en vez de darme a elegir, os adjunto el codigo. Y gracias por las respuestas.

```
`
    public class Main {
    static List<Prenda> alPrenda = new ArrayList<Prenda>();
    static Camisa camisa = new Camisa();
    static Pantalon pantalon = new Pantalon();
    static Calcetines calcetin = new Calcetines();
    static int opcion;
    static int eleccion;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do {
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            opcion = 0;
            System.out.println("------ MENU --------");
            System.out.println("1. Guardar prenda. ");
            System.out.println("2. Mostrar prendas. ");
            System.out.println("Elije la opcion deseada: ");
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        } while (opcion > 2);
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                do {
                System.out.println("------- MENU GUARDAR -------");
                System.out.println("1. Camisa. ");
                System.out.println("2. Pantalon. ");
                System.out.println("3. Calcetin. ");
                System.out.println("Elije la opcion deseada: ");
                eleccion = teclado.nextInt();
                } while (eleccion > 3);
                switch (eleccion) {
                case 1:
                camisa = new Camisa();
                System.out.println("------- GUARDAR CAMISA -------");
                System.out.println("Introduce el ID. ");
                camisa.setId(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce el precio. ");
                camisa.setPrecio(teclado.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Introdce la talla. ");
                camisa.setTalla(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce el color. ");
                camisa.setColor(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de cuello. ");
                camisa.setTipoCuello(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce si tiene bolsillo. (true o false)");
                if (teclado.nextBoolean()) {
                    camisa.setTieneBolsillo(true);
                } else {
                    camisa.setTieneBolsillo(false);
                }
                alPrenda.add(camisa);
                System.out.println("Camisa guardada");
                break;
                case 2:
                pantalon = new Pantalon();
                    System.out.println("------- GUARDAR PANTALON -------");
                    System.out.println("Introduce el ID. ");
                    pantalon.setId(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el precio. ");
                    pantalon.setPrecio(teclado.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("Introdce la talla. ");
                    pantalon.setTalla(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el color. ");
                    pantalon.setColor(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de cuello. ");
                    pantalon.setCorte(br.readLine());
                    alPrenda.add(pantalon);
                    System.out.println("Pantalon guardada");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    calcetin = new Calcetines();
                    System.out.println("------- GUARDAR CALCETIN -------");
                    System.out.println("Introduce el ID. ");
                    calcetin.setId(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el precio. ");
                    calcetin.setPrecio(teclado.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("Introdce la talla. ");
                    calcetin.setTalla(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el color. ");
                    calcetin.setColor(br.readLine());
                    alPrenda.add(calcetin);
                    System.out.println("Calcetin guardada");
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                mostrarPrendas();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    public static void mostrarPrendas() {
            for (int i = 0; i < alPrenda.size(); i++) {
                alPrenda.get(i).mostrarInformacion();
    }
  }
`
```

Me gustaria que al guardar una prenda me volviese a salir el menu principal, para volver a elegir si quier guardar otra prenda o que me muestre el array.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso es porque te falta añadir un break antes del segundo case de tu switch, quedaría así:

```
 public class Main {
    static List<Prenda> alPrenda = new ArrayList<Prenda>();
    static Camisa camisa = new Camisa();
    static Pantalon pantalon = new Pantalon();
    static Calcetines calcetin = new Calcetines();
    static int opcion;
    static int eleccion;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do {
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            opcion = 0;
            System.out.println("------ MENU --------");
            System.out.println("1. Guardar prenda. ");
            System.out.println("2. Mostrar prendas. ");
            System.out.println("Elije la opcion deseada: ");
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        } while (opcion > 2);
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                do {
                System.out.println("------- MENU GUARDAR -------");
                System.out.println("1. Camisa. ");
                System.out.println("2. Pantalon. ");
                System.out.println("3. Calcetin. ");
                System.out.println("Elije la opcion deseada: ");
                eleccion = teclado.nextInt();
                } while (eleccion > 3);
                switch (eleccion) {
                case 1:
                camisa = new Camisa();
                System.out.println("------- GUARDAR CAMISA -------");
                System.out.println("Introduce el ID. ");
                camisa.setId(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce el precio. ");
                camisa.setPrecio(teclado.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Introdce la talla. ");
                camisa.setTalla(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce el color. ");
                camisa.setColor(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de cuello. ");
                camisa.setTipoCuello(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Introduce si tiene bolsillo. (true o false)");
                if (teclado.nextBoolean()) {
                    camisa.setTieneBolsillo(true);
                } else {
                    camisa.setTieneBolsillo(false);
                }
                alPrenda.add(camisa);
                System.out.println("Camisa guardada");
                break;
                case 2:
                pantalon = new Pantalon();
                    System.out.println("------- GUARDAR PANTALON -------");
                    System.out.println("Introduce el ID. ");
                    pantalon.setId(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el precio. ");
                    pantalon.setPrecio(teclado.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("Introdce la talla. ");
                    pantalon.setTalla(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el color. ");
                    pantalon.setColor(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de cuello. ");
                    pantalon.setCorte(br.readLine());
                    alPrenda.add(pantalon);
                    System.out.println("Pantalon guardada");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    calcetin = new Calcetines();
                    System.out.println("------- GUARDAR CALCETIN -------");
                    System.out.println("Introduce el ID. ");
                    calcetin.setId(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el precio. ");
                    calcetin.setPrecio(teclado.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("Introdce la talla. ");
                    calcetin.setTalla(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Introduce el color. ");
                    calcetin.setColor(br.readLine());
                    alPrenda.add(calcetin);
                    System.out.println("Calcetin guardada");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                mostrarPrendas();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    public static void mostrarPrendas() {
            for (int i = 0; i < alPrenda.size(); i++) {
                alPrenda.get(i).mostrarInformacion();
    }
  }
```

Sin el break te sigue ejecutando el código que viene a continuación.

Comment: Gracias por las respuesta, pero al meter el segundo break; en cuanto guardo la prenda me cierra la aplicacion. ¿Cómo podria hacer para que al terminar de guardar una prenda me mostrase otra vez el menu principal, que me pregunte si quiero añadir o mostrar la prenda, y asi hasta que yo quiera terminar la ejecucion?.

Comment: Puedes meter todo el proceso dentro de un while(true) para que entre indefinidamente o hacerlo con una variable y añadir una opción al menú para terminar la ejecución ( creo que esta seria la forma mas acertada)

Comment: Perfecto:
Muchas gracias, he hecho lo que me has dicho de meter todo dentro de un while(repetir==true) que cambio a false cuando muestro las prendas